# Create profile and view table for each role or user?

Tags: sql-server, aspnet-development-server

I have big table in SQL srver
and users categorized to groups

I need to create a profile for each user
each user can add, update, edit a view table from the real big table
before the user exit,the data will be saved in the big table

Comment: Sample Data?? Your Attempt?? Any code??

Comment: plz, if possible, I need ideas or practical layout solutions.